# How to convert Erlang:timestamp() to normal date format?

Tags: timestamp, format, erlang

I would like to convert the result of erlang:timestamp() to the normal date type, Gregorian Calendar type.

Normal Date type means "Day-Month-Year, Hour:Minutes:seconds".

```
ExampleTime = erlang:timeStamp(),

ct:pal("~p", [ExampleTime]).
```

This shows **{1568,869478,181646}**

I guess the unit is the second, but not sure of what it stands for.

How it can be converted with code and its concept.
Be more specific, I do not know but for an example,

{1568, 869478, 181646} == {Year+Month,day,hour+minutes}.

Comment: I updated the question. Not exactly the same as the above format, but in normal type for daily use.

Comment: Sure ISO 8601 format is also okay

Answer (score 4):

Please, look at the documentation [erlang:timestamp()](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#timestamp-0), it says

> erlang:timestamp() -> Timestamp
>
> Types
>
> Timestamp = timestamp()
>
> timestamp() =
>
> ```
> {MegaSecs :: integer() >= 0,
>
>  Secs :: integer() >= 0,
>
> MicroSecs :: integer() >= 0}
> ```
>
> Returns current Erlang system time on the format {MegaSecs, Secs, MicroSecs}...

Then the module calendar of the stdlib library offers several conversion functions such as [calendar:now_to_datetime(Now)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html#now_to_datetime-1) :

```
1> calendar:now_to_datetime({1568,869478,181646}).
{{2019,9,19},{5,4,38}}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my code:

```
{{Y,M,D},{ H,MM,SS}} = calendar:now_to_datetime({MegaSecs,Secs,MicroSecs }),

lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~B-~2.10.0B-~2.10.0B ~2.10.0B:~2.10.0B:~2.10.0B", [Y, M, D,H,MM,SS])).

% result like 2019-09-18 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this function when it comes to converting to human readable timestamps from `erlang:timestamp()`:

```
format_utc_timestamp(TS, Separator) ->
    {_,_,Micro} = TS,
    {{Year,Month,Day},{Hour,Minute,Second}} = 
        calendar:now_to_universal_time(TS),
    io_lib:format("~4w-~2..0w-~2..0w~s~2..0w:~2..0w:~2..0w.~6..0w",
              [Year,Month,Day,Separator,Hour,Minute,Second,Micro]).
```

Where `TS` is the timestamp value of `{MegaSecs, Secs, MicroSecs}` and `Separator` is a string to be used to pretty print the timestamp. This will give you the format, with `T` as the separator:

```
2019-09-25T10:19:19.020202
```

If you'd like to get an [ISO 8601 timestamp](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6), you can do the following formatting on the last line of the function above:

```
io_lib:format("~4w-~2..0w-~2..0wT~w:~2..0w:~2..0wZ", [Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second])
```

Which will result in `2014-09-22T20:53:44Z`

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of generate ISO 8601 format:

```erlang
1> {{Year, Month, Day}, {Hour, Min, Sec}} = calendar:now_to_datetime(erlang:timestamp()).
{{2019,9,19},{15,7,3}}
2> list_to_binary(io_lib:format("~.4.0w-~.2.0w-~.2.0wT~.2.0w:~.2.0w:~.2.0w.0+00:00", [Year, Month, Day, Hour, Min, Sec])).
<<"2019-09-19T15:07:03.0+00:00">>
```

Or you can use `erlang:universaltime()` instead `calendar:now_to_datetime(erlang:timestamp())` for get universal time